# findViewById() returns null for a view found by getChildAt()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-source, findviewbyid

I'm making some modifications to the AOSP SystemUI app, and have run into a very particular problem when trying to run it on an arbitrary device: `findViewById()` returns `null`, while navigating through the its children reveals that it's really there.

I'm working with [this AOSP source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r2.1/com/android/systemui/recent/RecentsPanelView.java/) and building it through `lunch full-eng` and `make`. It compiles fine, but SystemUI crashes with the IllegalArgumentException in the logic following line 337:

```
mRecentsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.recents_container);
[...]
if (mRecentsContainer instanceof RecentsHorizontalScrollView){
    [...]
} else if (mRecentsContainer instanceof RecentsVerticalScrollView){
    [...]
}
else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("missing Recents[Horizontal]ScrollView");
}
```

A bit of debugging reveals that `mRecentsContainer` is in fact `null`.

I considered that perhaps a layout was being inflated that didn't contain that particular view, so to check, I navigated recursively through all the view's children using `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()`. That wasn't the case; `@id/recents_container` was right there, two levels deep:

```
> @id/recents_root (7f0e0070) [RecentsPanelView]: (2 children)
--> @id/recents_bg_protect (7f0e0071) [FrameLayout]: (2 children)
----> @id/recents_container (7f0e0072) [RecentsVerticalScrollView]: (1 children)
------> @id/recents_linear_layout (7f0e0073) [LinearLayout]: (0 children)
----> @id/recents_no_apps (7f0e0074) [FrameLayout]: (1 children)
------> [unnamed] (ffffffff) [TextView]
--> @id/recents_dismiss_button (7f0e0075) [View]
```

A singular hint appears in Logcat from `system_process` when installing the app:

> 12-11 22:38:01.090: W/ResourceType(165): Failure getting entry for 0x7f060000 (t=5 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)

Inspecting `R.java` in the `SystemUI_intermediates` directory reveals that it points to a seemingly unrelated `status_bar_recents_app_label_color`, which is simply a defined color in `res/values/color.xml`.

What can be causing this? Is the layout not inflating correctly because I'm running it on a device I didn't compile against? I considered that perhaps the problem may be SystemUI's references to internal Android resources, which might not map correctly to those on my device. Is that possible?

Comment: I haven't gone through the code, just a suggestion: maybe you are trying to findViewById before it has been added to the parent.

Comment: The snippet I provided executes within `onFinishInflate()`, so that shouldn't be the problem. Note that the code is straight from AOSP's 4.0.4_r2.1 branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently some generated files were sticking around.

Rebuilding the source from scratch through `make clean` resolved it.

Alternatively, I've figured out that deleting the following intermediate directories makes for a faster build, but am not 100% sure that this covers all directories:

```
rm -rf out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/SystemUI_intermediates/
rm -rf out/target/common/R/com/android/systemui
rm -rf out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/
rm -f /out/target/common/R/com/android/internal/R.java
rm -rf out/target/product/generic/obj/PACKAGING/
rm -f out/target/product/generic/system/app/SystemUI.apk
```